# File type for uploading audio file with Apache FTP jar

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I have created FTP setup to upload .3gp files to my FTP.

All files are going without error, but now i realized, after downloading no file is playable. It felt ftp have corrupted all audio files.

Can u suggest how to fix? I have used Apache commons FTP for this.

Comment: maybe you transferred the files in ascii mode, instead on binary?

Comment: i read the on various sites and documentation, everywhere it is mentioned that, apache default filetype is ASCII.

Comment: though i could able to sort the issue now with ftp4j jar. It is not corrupting any file. Still if some one can advice on correct filetype for apache will be nice.